# Android: Switch views in tabs without leaving current tab. Like USA Today App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm in the process of building a sports team app and have created my own tab bar as opposed to using Google's tab code.  I like the way USA Today's App works.
[USA Today App](http://androinica.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/usatoday_android_250x250.jpg)
When you choose amongst the different categories of news, only the view below changes, it doesn't switch to a completely new screen/activity.  How are they doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot, it looks like the different categories are contained within a `Gallery` view.  Through `setOnItemSelectedListener`, you can register for a callback when the user chooses a different item.  You can then programmatically change the main `View` or populate it with new data.

For example, say you have a `ViewFlipper` and a `Gallery` defined in your layout where the order of the items in your `Gallery` correspond to the ordering of the `Views` in the `ViewFlipper`.  In your Activity, you use `findViewById` to get references to those `Views`(the flipper and gallery variables).  You could then do:

```
    myGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I found this and it got what I needed: http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/android-viewflipper-within-tabhost-for-tabs-with-different-views-and-better-memory - However, if you can point to examples of your description here, I'd be willing to try it.  Michaelg was right though, there is A LOT of coding to do if I use this method.

Comment: I added some sample code for you.  I have done something like this and it did not strike me as having to do a lot of extra coding to make it work.  Try to find commonality across your Views and follow good OO design and patterns to reduce the amount of coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActivityGroup to switch between different view within a current tab. here is a demo for that.  http://androidgenuine.com/

[Complete Demo of ActivityGroup](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

Comment: `ActivityGroup` is deprecated. Fragments have replaced it. Also that link is not accurately pointing to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how they have implemented that feature in their app. They are most likely just altering the View tree, i.e. replacing one View with another programmatically. The biggest problem with this is that you usually need a lot of code to support each of the Views that could be shown within a particular Activity -- code for loading data, handling user taps, etc. You could put a lot of that code inside a custom View class instead of having it in the Activity. If putting "business logic" inside a View seems perverse, then I would recommend using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). Then changing tabs can be handled using [FragmentTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html). These were added in Android 3.0, but there is a [compatibility package](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html) that let's you use these on Android 1.6+.